# Generic term for dates not present in some/all calendar months?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, dates

Some days/dates are not present in all (Gregorian) calendar months. Specifically, five months of the year do not have a '31st', and February does not have a '29th' (except in Leap years) nor a '30th'.

Is there a generic term for these days/dates that are present only in selected months?

Example sentence:

> If recurring event would fall on a [date-not-present-in-that/all-calendar-month(s)], its occurrence will fall on the last day of that month.

Comment: Hmm... Is there a name for those days in your language? I don't think there's a specific name for it... :-/

Comment: great question, but I believe there is no real term for this in English.  Maybe "longer-month extra-days" would work in say a technical discussion. Don[t forget "31" is the only one you are really discussing. (February is a special case.)

Comment: @Neeku, My dying native language? None that I know of. :( Regardless, I'm writing a document in english so I need(ed) an english word or jargon maybe.

Comment: @JoeBlow, Yeah I had a feeling. English is my 2nd language and I haven't heard anything like it. I just rephrased what I was trying to say instead; kinda awkward but couldn't be helped.

I actually had 29, 30, and 31 in mind as they are not present in all months. "Regular" days would be 1-28 as all months have them.

Comment: Hmm Czar. What language is it, out of curiosity? I'm coming from a [very rational calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar#Month_names) that's well divided into months, therefore I've never found a logic behind the Gregorian calendar, and its months and number of days, etc.

Comment: Days after 28th are **in the fifth week** of the month (or "after the end of the fourth week" if that's easier to visualise). Only a comment, because it's really too short for an answer.

Comment: @Neeku, [Waray-waray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waray-Waray_language). That's an interesting calendar; I've never used any other calendar besides Gregorian unfortunately.

Comment: "If *a* special recurring date *lands on the 30th or 31st of a month*, it becomes the 28th instead."

Comment: In MS Outlook, if you enter a monthly recurring event for the X day of the month (X = 29, 30, or 31) you get a warning message "Some months have fewer than X days. For these months, the occurrence will fall on the last day of the month."

Comment: I've rephrased both the example sentence & the Q (and possibly slightly broadened it). Previous example sentence implied that an event on, say, 30th/31st would be 'moved' to 28th *irrespective of whether that month actually contained a 30th/31st*. Similarly, previous Q. asked for name for dates not present in *all* months (*i.e.* would always include 30th/31st); I've modified it to refer to dates not present in "that/all months" (*i.e.* would include 30th/31st for only relevant months) - but there may be no practical difference.

Comment: The term, if one were to find one, would almost certainly be from Latin, and would refer to the fact that the extra days were "stolen" from other months (particularly February) to glorify the specific deities and Roman emperors for whom the recipient months were named.

Comment: @HotLicks I understand where you're coming from, but 5 months had 31 days even before July & August stole 2 from February.

Comment: @TrevorD - And they were evenly/fairly spaced through the calendar year, and leaving at most one "odd" day in each month (which could have then been called simply the "extra day" or some such).

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not disagreeing with you in principle.  Slighty OT: I presume that, prior to the Roman re-naming June & the predecessors of July & August all had 30 days, while Dec & Jan (which adjoin) both had 31 days - so the shorter months weren't that evenly spaced.

Comment: @TrevorD -- Many years ago (like maybe 50) I read a complete account of the whole thing, but have forgotten the details.  A couple of years ago I looked for details on the predecessor scheme, but could not find anything definitive.  I gather the original version only existed for a very brief time.

Comment: Good edit, I can now understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I've thought of something I've seen in computer programming for these issues:

post28Days

ie, the days bigger than 28.  you could also say "super-28 days" or similar.

I don't know if it's relevant to your situation.

Comment: Yeah, that's clever; I'm actually writing a software spec. :D

Comment: hope it helps, ciao !

Answer (score 2):

February 29 is called the "leap day" because it's not in every year. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29

That doesn't answer your question though. Sorry I don't have enough reputation points yet to just post a comment

Comment: February 29 (and other similar days in other calendars) are technically called [intercalary days](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intercalary).